# @Async implementation in custom Mule plugin

Tags: asynchronous, mule, connector

I am working on custom mule connector. Connector needs to call a rest service asynchronously.

One way is to embed connector in asynchrous scope component.

Do we have any option in Mule plugin dev kit?

Thanks in advance.